# Output of 5/0 V for H/L of comparator when its input compares to 12V

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier, comparator

If my LM311 comparator is powered with +24V into VCC and 0V into VEE, how can it provide +5V (H) when its positive input is greater than 12 and 0V (L) when its positive input is less than 12V?

Here is my attempt, but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUyVPB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have GND of the voltage regulator and the negative of your signal source to the center of your voltage divider. They should be connected to ground instead.

The voltage divider is simply providing a reference voltage of 12 V for the comparator, it is not a virtual ground like you might see in an amplifier circuit. All of your ground references should go to the 24 V negative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV4ULq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Looks right to me. And on the LM311, don't forget to tie EMIT_OUT to GND as well. Leave BALANCE and BAL/STRB floating.

Comment: ... also depending on how much power you need to draw from OUT, if you want to save yourself a component, a simple voltage divider between the comparator's collector output ("OUT") and GND (e.g., 380k and 100k) would make the middle of the voltage divider read as zero or 5V -- read your "TTL_OUT" signal there. 380k isn't a typical resistor but 330k + 47k in series would be close enough. Just make sure R3 is a much stronger pull-up (10x or more) than the divider resistor. Then you could ditch the 7805.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a regulator providing 5V, then @GodJihyo's answer is perfect.

If the regulator has no other function than to produce 5V for this particular task, then it's overkill, and I have another suggestion.

The LM311 has a user-configurable output transistor, which makes it trivially easy to clamp the output to a 5V maximum with only a single 5V zener diode and resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVHPBl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

No need for *any* regulator here.

Comment: This seems like a great optimization; could you please elaborate on why this works?

Comment: @ludicrous the diode simply prevents the voltage across it from exceeding 5V. It's safe to short-circuit the diode by turning on the transistor, since it does not oppose *less than* 5.1V across it, it just won't allow more than that.

Comment: I'm getting values between 0-40mV in the output with this circuit